# Show that the number of compares used by mergesort is monotonically increasing (C(N+1) > C(N) for all N > 0)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

This is a question from Algorithms 4th Edition about MergeSort. Since we proved earlier that the number of compares, C(N) = N * log(N) for N being a power of 2. I answered this question by finding the derivative of N * log(N) and showing that this derivative is increasing for N > 0. Is this the correct approach or is there an alternate way to solve this question?

Comment: add your solution also in text format here to help others get alternate solution more quickly

Answer (score 2):

No, that approach doesn't work.  If you've only proved a rule for powers of two, you have no basis to assume that the same rule applies for all the numbers in between -- especially not the numbers between integers, which N cannot even assume. (I'm guessing that you used a continuous derivative, which of course only applies to continuous functions)

If you want to prove that the maximum or minimum number of comparisons monotonically increases for all integers > 0, you can use induction.

First, demonstrate that it is true for all N from 2<sup>0</sup> and 2<sup>1</sup>, and then show that if it's true for all N = 2<sup>x</sup> through 2<sup>x+1</sup>, then it's true for 2<sup>x+1</sup> through 2<sup>x+2</sup>.